# Data won't load from text file - ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 3, got 1)

Tags: python

Can't get this text data to load:

```
Al,95191,619851,
Joe,651651,616951,
```

The load module:

```
def loadPlayers():
    Roster = {}
    filename = input("Filename to load: ")
    inFile = open(filename, "rt")
    print("Loading data...")
    while True:
        inLine = inFile.readline()
        if not inLine:
            break
        inLine = inLine[:-1]
        name, phone, jersey = inLine.split(",")
        Roster[name] = Players(name, phone, jersey)
    print("Data Loaded Successfully.")
    inFile.close()
    return Roster
```

I get this error:

```
line 103, in loadPlayers name, phone, jersey = inLine.split(",")
  ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 3, got 1)
```

Comment: Do you have a blank line in the input? (Look into the `with` keyword for opening the file and you can just iterate over the file without using `while`, e.g. `for inLine in inFile:`

Comment: Is your indentation right? As I read your loop, you throw away all the lines but the last. If that last is blank, then `split` will give you an array with a single entry, namely, the empty string. Try `"".split(",")` to see what I mean.

Comment: You've got a line with less than three comma-separated values in it. You could print out the offending line by putting a `try:` & `except ValueError:` around the `inLine.split(",")` and then print the line in the `except` clause to see exactly which one it is. If you do nothing else after that, the line will simply be ignored.

Comment: Side-note: Use [the `csv` module, e.g. `csv.reader`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html), don't roll your own CSV parsing code. And it's much more straightforward to do `for inLine in inFile:` (or in this case, `for name, phone, jersey in csv.reader(inFile):` or some variant thereof if you have inconsistent field counts) rather than an infinite loop with a `readline` call and a test and `break`.

Comment: The save file is a TXT file. The save module of the code generated and saved the file in this format  Al,95191,619851,
Joe,651651,616951,

Comment: @AlMedina: CSV is just text, formatted a specific way. The `.txt` extension doesn't mean anything; if the contents are CSV, parse it as CSV.

Answer (score 0):

You can improve the script a little to parse better some cases of extra data not formated as suspected.

```
def loadPlayers():
    Roster = {}
    filename = input("Filename to load: ")
    inFile = open(filename, "rt")
    print("Loading data...")
    while True:
        inLine = inFile.readline()
        if not inLine:
            break
        inLine = inLine[:-1].split(",")
        if len(inLine) != 3:
            continue
        name, phone, jersey = inLine.split(",")
        Roster[name] = Players(name, phone, jersey)
    print("Data Loaded Successfully.")
    inFile.close()
    return Roster
```